# Why am I unable to upload this dataframe into a table in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-import-wizard

When I try to use the data import wizard I get this error saying: "Can't analyze file. Please try to change encoding type."

I saved my data frame as a csv delimited file
Here is the data I wish to import into a table in MySQL Workbench
[2020_NFL_NFC_Standings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeOGU.png)

Any suggestions?